# C# ToastNotification in Windows 8. ExpirationTime is not working

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-8, notifications, toast

I am working with the ToastNotification object in Windows 8 and they work fine.

The only attribute that seems to have problems is ExpirationTime that should set the moment when the message fades away if it is not clicked by a user.

```
ToastNotification toast = new ToastNotification(toastXml);

toast.ExpirationTime = DateTimeOffset.Now.AddDays(1); ;
toast.Activated += ToastActivated;
toast.Dismissed += ToastDismissed;

ToastNotificationManager.CreateToastNotifier(APP_ID).Show(toast);
```

I have tried as well as the example in the code that i post:

```
toast.ExpirationTime =  System.DateTime.Today.AddDays(1)
toast.ExpirationTime = new DateTimeOffset(DateTime.Now.AddDays(1));
```

But it does not work. The toast message shows correctly but it disappears after a few seconds later.

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found an answer to my own question. 
I post it, it might be usefull to someone in future.

[image]

The really ExpirationTime used is the "show notification for" setted in the Pc Settings.
The ExpirationTime that you set in the code can't exceed this value.